# How to do teleoperation in Pybullet

Tags: python, bulletphysics

I am using pybullet to control a robot. I wanted to ask how can I write a teleoperation programm to move the end effector of a robot in Pybullet?

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to move the body to the new place, you will have to deal with inertia, and collision on the way.

Instead, remove the body from the world, then recreate it at the new position.
It sounds drastic, but fairly cheap.
Bullet is great at dealing with pools of bodies.

Answer (score 0):

Once you added the imformation of end effector, you can cotr it by using setmotorcontrol or array with inverse kinematiccalculation